# Maintaining the member's hours spent in the organization : Drupal Website

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, drupal-modules

I am running a Drupal powered website of my college. Each student has a certain (fixed) number of hours to complete in any kind of sport. Now, I am maintaining various sports on my website using CCK and Views.

Now, if a student plays some sport say A, he will go to the website and check out A's details. Also, after specified period of time a link appears on the A page where student can check out his hours. He can then log in and check his hours for A. And similarly, for others. Important point here is for different sports he will see differently managed hours.

There will also be a point where he can see his total hours that have been approved.

Most of the hours in my website are uploaded using .csv file. So, I am trying to do this mainly without the Drupal Modules. When someone uploads a .csv file I take the page title as a parameter and create a table with name as page title which is nothing but my event name. And, when some student queries his hours, I send it as a hidden parameter the title of the page and then return the hours of the student.

But, now I want to do this using a Drupal Module because this approach is somehow not working. Can anyone suggest me a Drupal Module for the above?

I tried using many modules for above, most close being User Points, in which I perceive points as hours. But this had some problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not clearly stated, but this can be a solution:

- Students are users of the site.
- Sports are nodes.
- Sessions are nodes.
- Sessions have a start and end date, two Date fields.
- Sessions are related to Sports using a nodereference field.
- Sessions are related to Students using a multivalued userreference field.
- When a Students is associated to a Session, it means it has *completed* some hours of the Sport related to that Session. The total number of hours are determined by the Session's start and end dates.
- Using Views and [Views Attach](http://drupal.org/project/views_attach) you can

  - Display upcoming Sessions for a Sport on its page.
  - Display recent previous Sessions for a Sport on its page.
  - Display the latest *completed* Sessions for a student on his/her profile page.
- Using a custom module and Views theming, on a Sport page you can add links to each of its recent previous Sessions to allow a student (ie. a user) to associate him/herself with that Session.

Comment: Actually, the start date and end date are not exactly my indicators of hours that need to be uploaded. Sometimes, we give double time and sometimes even half of the time actually spent. So, we manually update the hours by uploading a .csv file which has two fields the username and hours. So, I am a bit confused how can I achieve the .csv upload facility with any of the drupal modules.

Comment: You could try the Data module to store/retrieve your data (see http://drupal.org/project/data).
You could use the Feeds module to load your CSV file into a Data managed table or nodes (see http://drupal.org/project/feedapi_data).